# ActiveRecord assign_attributes extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2.0

I have a method on my Rails app to warehouse data from a web service. After retrieving and formatting the data, I'm using `assign_attributes` to update the model before doing some other logic and saving. The problem is that assigning the variables is crazy slow! Assigning 3 properties (a string and two booleans) is taking between 1 and 3 seconds. My full application needs to assign 30, and it's taking upwards of a minute for each object to be updated.

Sample code:

```
...

# @trips_hash is a hash of { trip_numbers => trip_details<Hash> }
# @bi_trips is an array of <Trip> (ActiveRecord::Base) objects from the database

@trips_hash.each do |trip_number, trip_details|
  trip = @bi_trips.select { |t| t.number == trip_number }.first
  ...
  time_started = Time.now # For performance profiling
  trip.assign_attributes( stage: 'foo', all_intl: true, active: false )
  p "Done in #{(Time.now - time_started).round(2)} s."
end

...
```

Here are results for the above code:

```
"Done in 0.0 s."
"Done in 1.71 s."
"Done in 2.09 s."
"Done in 3.36 s."
"Done in 1.45 s."
"Done in 1.99 s."
"Done in 1.63 s."
"Done in 0.59 s."
"Done in 1.61 s."
"Done in 1.56 s."
"Done in 2.25 s."
"Done in 1.42 s."
"Done in 1.53 s."
"Done in 1.61 s."
```

Am I going crazy? It seems like it shouldn't take 1-3 seconds to assign 3 properties of an object. I get similar results breaking it into

```
trip.stage = 'foo'
trip.all_intl = false
trip.active = true
```

Comment: Please show your trip model. If there is any of `stage=` `all_intl=`or `active=` method defined, there are no boundries on how slow it can be.

Comment: Are there any callbacks on the trip model? Like sending notifications to a third party api or whatever?

Comment: @BroiSatse No custom setters in the model. @Albin There is a `before_save` callback that's an `||= 0.0` for a few of the fields, and there's an `after_save` callback that's outside of the scope of this as it doesn't run until later.

Comment: @ChrisPatten - Can you run all the assignment one by one to say which one is slow?

Comment: @BroiSatse - Doing them one by one yields similar results. I'm starting to think part of the slowness might be the VM that it's running on. The same code run natively on a newer MacBook Pro does each one in around 0.5 seconds (still slower than I'd expect but more acceptable).